# How to read a zip file of 1000+ similarly structured json files into a single dataframe in R?

Tags: r, json

I know that I can already use jsonlite and rjson. But let's say that I have a folder with over 1000 jsons. What is the best way to read those all into an R dataframe?

```
json_file <- fromJSON(file = "myjson.json")
```

Comment: useful functions are: `list.files` read them all to list with `lapply` then `merge` them to one dataframe:  `Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all=T), list.of.data.frames)`

Comment: More likely that to get "a single dataframe" the intention is to use `do.call(rbind, list.of.data.frames)` than to actually merge them, but it isn't clear from the question.

Answer (score 1):

The `rio` package can quite effortlessly read the contents of a zipfile into a list of dataframes.

First let's create a reproducible example, also using `rio` and the built-in `zip` function.

```
library(rio)

export(data.frame(x=1:2, y=3:4), "foo1.json")
#> Loading required namespace: jsonlite
export(data.frame(x=5:6, y=7:8), "foo2.json")
zip("foo.zip", c("foo1.json", "foo2.json"))
```

So now we have a zipfile with some json files in it. To import we simply:

```
foo_list <- import_list("foo.zip")
```

Now we have a list of dataframes with the same structure. Now we do the usual thing to put them all together:

```
do.call(rbind, foo_list)
#>        x y
#> foo1.1 1 3
#> foo1.2 2 4
#> foo2.1 5 7
#> foo2.2 6 8
```

Answer (score -1):

Note that this depends on your .jsons having the same headers, allowing you to easily bind them together.

```
lf=Sys.glob("*.json")

combdf <- data.frame(colA=(), colB=())
currdf <- data.frame()

for (i in length(lf)){
  currdf <- fromJSON(file = lf[i])
  combdf <- rbind(combdf, currdf)
}
```

Comment: Building a data frame like this in a loop is terribly inefficient and is one of the (almost) "never do" things in R. Far better to create a list of data frames using something like `jl <- lapply(seq_along(lf), function(i) fromJSON(file=lf[i]))` followed by `do.call(rbind, jl)` which is a canonical `R` way of doing this. (My suggestion was not tested and not run but is a suggestion only.) Also you didn't say how to handle the fact the files themselves are in a zip file.